# How to delete the dates? (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite3-python

[This is my data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl8ak.png)

I want to delete all the dates with day 26, for example
But code like this doesn't work:

```
CURSOR.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {name}_schedule WHERE date == {date}")
```

I do not know sql at all, so idk what to do :c

Comment: `SELECT` doesn't delete anything, it returns the contents of those rows. Use `DELETE` to delete rows.

Comment: Use a placeholder instead of `{date}`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: The problem with your query is that you need quotes around `{date}`. But if you use a prepared statement as in the above link, you won't have that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql could be something like this

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE strftime('%d', date_column) = '26'
```